# Akka pipe completion priority with onSuccess

Tags: akka, future

In my actor, I do something like:

```
//upon receiving a message
Future myFuture = Futures.succesful(doSomething());
myFuture.onSuccess(new OnSuccess<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object object) throws Throwable {
                doSomethingLong(object);
            }
        }, dispatcher);
Patterns.pipe(myFuture).to(sender());
```

Will my sender receive the message response at the time where "doSomething()" completes, i.e. as soon as the first future completes, or after the "doSomethingLong()" completes, i.e. after the onSuccess handler operations have completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that `onSuccess` is [deprecated](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onSuccess[U](pf:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) since Scala 2.12.0. Consider moving to `foreach` or `onComplete`*

`onSuccess` attaches a function to be executed when the target future is completed with a value. Therefore the callback and the message send to the actor is going to happen concurrently.

If you want a sequential behaviour, use `map` instead of `onSuccess`.

Comment: That is a valid assumption, and also what I thought should happen, but I have found myself doubting this when trying to improve performance of an app recently (it really seemed the sender would not get the message until the onComplete completed, but I wasn't able to prove it 100%). Do you have any source for this that completely removes my doubts?

Comment: (Btw, we were on Scala 2.11 since we were using Akka within Java)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `onSuccess` and the `pipe` will happen concurrently.

If you don't want a possibly failed invocation of `doSomethingLong()` to affect the outcome, and you want it to have executed before piping it to sender, then I'd suggest the following:

```
Future myFuture = Futures.successful(doSomething());
Patterns.pipe(myFuture.andThen(new OnComplete<Object>() {
    public void onComplete(Throwable failure, Object result) {
      if (failure != null)
        doSomethingLong(result);
    }
  }, dispatcher)).to(sender());
```

Comment: I suppose that if the answer comes from the man himself that's a reliable enough source to confirm what I thought was right. I'll upvote your answer but mark the other as solution since it arrived earlier